How to prove that $f(n):=n+3$ is injective in Lean 4?
So I have recently been using Robo (another Lean4 theorem proving game) to try to get more in depth understanding of how tactics and theorem-proving works in Lean4.
I am currently stuck on Injectivity Level 1/10, where I have to prove the following:
Objects
f: ℤ → ℤ := fun (n : ℤ) ↦ n + 3
Goal
Injective f

I currently have this as my proof
unfold Injective
intro x y
intro h1

with this as my current state:
Objects
f: ℤ → ℤ := fun (n : ℤ) ↦ n + 3
x y: ℤ

Assumptions
h1: f x = f y

Goal
x = y

My question is: What do I do from here? I can't use the tactics simp, tauto, decide, ring, since the first three fail to make progress, and ring does nothing.
I can't use apply congr_arg f since along with apply congr_arg h1, this actually crashes the level. Also, applying congr_fun or comp_apply to either f or h1 since that just gives an error.

Please post working snippest of code that we can actually try out. It might be the case that your code is missing some detail that can only be visible if you show the exact code that you're working with. (Not in your case, but I am saying this as a general principle.)

Thanks to @KevinBuzzard's comment, I was able to figure it out.
Final proof:
intro x y eq
simp_rw[f] at eq
linarith

However, what went wrong with the original proof? Really nothing. In fact, it seems that if I had just remembered to use the simp_rw tactic, I could have been perfectly fine. However in the later worlds, it just seems to be used so little - with other useful tactics available, such as assumption, constructor and ring - so it just hadn't been my go-to in this case.
In fact, the game gives a hint after using intro x y eq that could've steered me in the right direction had I been paying a bit more attention:

Du: Jetzt will ich wohl mit der Definition von f die Annahme eq vereinfachen.

In English:

You: Now I probably want to simplify the assumption eq with the definition of f.


Here are some typical ways of proving your result.
import Mathlib.Tactic.Linarith

def f: ℤ → ℤ := fun (n : ℤ) ↦ n + 3

lemma CrSb0001_one : Function.Injective f := by
   -- No need to unfold Function.Injective, as intro will force that
  intro x y eq
  -- But we do need to unfold f in the assumption eq
  unfold f at eq
  -- Now there are several ways to do it.
  -- First option: use apply? tactic to find the correct
  -- lemma. (Type "apply?" and when it gives you an answer
  -- click on it.)
  exact (Int.add_right_inj 3).mp eq -- generated using apply?

-- Exploring the lemma Int.add_right_inj a little further reveals
-- an annoying inconsistency in Mathlib:

#check Int.add_right_inj -- gives i + k = j + k ↔ i = j
#check add_right_inj     -- gives k + i = k + j ↔ i = j

-- So instead of Int.add_right_inj we could use add_left_inj.
-- Someone should fix these naming inconsistencies...

lemma CrSb0001_two : Function.Injective f := by
  intro x y eq
  unfold f at eq
  -- Second option: like option 1, but once we know that the
  -- lemma is add_left_inj, we can apply it like this:
  apply (add_left_inj _).mp
  assumption

-- But we really don't want to do any of the above and just
-- use tactics. Here are a couple of ways of doing it.

lemma CrSb0001_three : Function.Injective f := by
  intros x y eq
  unfold f at eq
  linarith -- a tactic for linear arithmetic

lemma CrSb0001_five : Function.Injective f := by
  simp_all_arith [Function.Injective, f]
  -- you can discover the tactic simp_all_arith by typing "sim" and
  -- when Lean fires up automatic completion choices, you will see 
  -- this tactic. We also have to tell it it's allowed to unfold 
  -- Function.Inxjective and f.


You can also use omega instead of linarith. It only works for Nat and Int and some related types (while linarith works over linearly ordered fields as well), but it is also more powerful than linarith (e.g. it can take advantage of facts related to divisibility as well). It's also built-in to Lean, and doesn't require Mathlib.

The naming inconsistency is fixed in https://github.com/leanprover/lean4/pull/6106.

Thanks for the fix!

It seems that you should unfold f at h1 to make progress.

This does not work actually - f isn't a "known" constant in this case

How about dsimp [f] at h1? I'm not familiar with the game so I don't know what techniques you've been taught / are allowed.

@KevinBuzzard simp_rw[f] at eq works (rewriting the first line of the proof as intro x y eq) and what I have now for an assumption is x+3=y+3, thanks! I was thinking that maybe I could use simp_rw instead since this doesn't have dsimp.

@KevinBuzzard I figured it out, thanks for the suggestion! I just had to write linarith for the last line in the proof afterwards.
